# RaspPi / raspbmc is turning on my TV

Tags: raspbmc, usb-power

newby here,

I have a raspbmc connected via HDMI to a CEC enabled smart TV. power is also coming from the TV via USB - everything more than fine, I really like it.

BUT: When I turn off the system (via Pis poweroff) the TV is also shut down - thats ok for me. But if I leave the setting as it is, after some time, my TV gets started, showing the xbmc portal - the same as I would have powered it on myself.

I know that TV sets can be started via HDMI, but that would mean my pi starts somehow. Is there any kind of cronjob starting the pi after some hours? I guess the USB port of my TV is constantly on, otherwise the pi couldn't do something on hdmi port.

I don't like it to get my TV turned on during the night, no idea how to avoid it,... you?

thx in advance

airwulf

Comment: is the Pi powered by the tvs USB ports? because if you are shutting down the pi then the only way it will boot again is if you cycle its power supply.

Comment: What is the TV model? Does it have internet connectivity?

Answer (score 2):

You might try with another USB power source and see what happens. If the RPi is truly shutdown, it would not be able to run a cron job to start itself back up. However a smart TV might not be totally shutdown (ie in stand-by/low power mode) and if it power-cycled the USB port, the RPi would reboot and then turn up the TV display and show the default XBMC graphics. Also, most Linux system have an "uptime" command which will show how long it has been running. That would help in determining if the RPi rebooted.